Monitor system performance during simulations
Sorry for the repost.
I am running simulations using ROS 2 and Gazebo, and I’ve noticed a specific issue over time: when I call services provided by the simulation, they initially succeed on the first attempt. However, after some time, I need to call the same service multiple times before receiving a successful response.
The problem doesn’t appear to be a general performance issue (e.g., simulation speed), but rather a degradation in the responsiveness of the services. I suspect this might be caused by resource usage (e.g., CPU, memory, or communication bottlenecks) or internal issues in the simulation.
I am looking for suggestions on how to:

Monitor relevant system-level metrics (e.g., CPU usage, memory consumption, ROS 2 or Gazebo node communication performance).

Debug service-related bottlenecks or delays in ROS 2 or Gazebo simulator (e.g., tracing service requests/responses, analyzing logs, etc.).

Identify any potential issues within Gazebo that might impact service responsiveness.


My OS is Ubuntu 22.04, ROS 2 Humble, Gazebo Fortress. I'm running the simulation within an Apptainer container.
Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
